# The meaning of 'stretch' here

Tags: word-meaning

This is from 'Mothers and Sons' by Colm Toibin.

> It was March and a thin frost was beginning to settle. The road had
>   been widened **for stretches**, and the car lights beamed on wooden
>   fences instead of the old ditches. The road was no more the hidden,
>   almost guilty thing it had been, huddled away from the land around.
>   There were fewer accidents now, she supposed.

I looked up the definition of [stretch](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stretch) and still not sure which one. Is the road widened in terms of a width only or a continuous length?

Comment: [*stretch*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stretch): "2. *countable noun* - A stretch of road, water, or land is a length or area of it." So it is referring to certain lengths of the road.

Comment: The road gets widened along certain lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we say:

> They had been driving **for hours**.

we mean that they had been on the road for a single length of time lasting several (or many) hours.

The preposition **for** introduces a span of measure.

> They had been wandering in the desert for forty years.

The author should  have written "**in** stretches" if the intended meaning was "in various (non-contiguous) sections of road" or "here and there along its length".

> The road had been widened in stretches.

When there are several stretches, possibly interrupted, rather than one continuous stretch, we expect an adjective:

> They sat in silence for long stretches.

Other native speakers may understand these phrases differently.